# NSTextView scroll view cuts off text

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, nstextview

I've dropped an `NSTextView` from Interface builder into my storyboard file. I'm setting the `stringValue` to a pretty-printed JSON string returned from an API endpoint. When the string is set, the scroll view containing the `NSTextView` (Which Apple adds by default in IB) doesn't get the correct content size, and therefore you can't scroll to see the whole content.

```
selectedEndpoint.refreshHandler({ [weak self] (result) in

    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

    switch result {
    case .success(let responseString):
        strongSelf.responses[strongSelf.selectedTab] = responseString
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            strongSelf.responseTextView.string = responseString
            strongSelf.responseTextView.needsLayout = true
        }
        break
    case .failure(_):
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            strongSelf.responseTextView.string = ""
            strongSelf.responseTextView.needsLayout = true
        }
        break
    }
})
```

See attached screenshots:

[image: App Image]

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: Did you change any settings of the text view or add contraints?

Comment: Not the Text View itself, but the scroll view it's contained in has been constrained using vertical distance to the label and the other sides to 20pts from the superview. Only thing I disabled on the text view was switching editing off